# sed d command with 2 patterns

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

My file.txt contains the following:

```
abc
123
abcd
1234
abcde
12345
```

I ran the sed command below:

```
sed '/^[a-z]/,/[a-z]$/d' alphabet3.txt
```

Doesn't it mean delete from the first line that starts with an alphabet through the first line that ends with an alphabet? So I was expecting my output to be:

```
1234
abcde
12345
```

Since "abc" starts with an alphabet and "abcd" ends with an alphabet. Therefore, 1-3 are deleted. But my actual output is:

```
1234
```

I think I am clearly missing something.

Answer (score 1):

From [the GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html):

> An address range matches lines starting from where the first address
>   matches, and continues until the second address matches (inclusively).

It's the first address that really matters. The second address need not match, in which case the range will cover till the end of file.

If we invert your command (printing only matching lines instead of deleting them), you can see that's what happens:

```
$ sed -n '/^[a-z]/,/[a-z]$/p' bar
abc
123
abcd
abcde
12345
```

Comment: Why isn't 1234 selected? I am still not sure what your command /^[a-z]/,/[a-z]$/p' is doing exactly

Comment: Why should it be? The range you gave ended before it and started again after it, so there is no reason for it be included. And my command does what I said - "printing only matching lines"